# XC8 Compiler setup on CLion for PIC Development

Tags: clion, pic, mplab, xc8

I am new to the embedded systems development space.

My problem is I can't find a way to setup my CLion for development with the XC8 compiler on the PIC16f1779. I have limited knowledge on compilers and CMake also its my first time using C/C++.

The IntelliJ IDE is amazing and I would love to use CLion instead of MPLab X IDE for development.
The school I am at use MPLAB for teaching but its just terrible.

I am using Mac M1 and I am trying to migrate development from MPlab to CLion.

Any help would be appreciated

I have already tried to configure another compiler as XC8 but don't know what exactly to change in the toolchain config in CLion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you being a newbie, I strongly recommend that you stick with MPLAB X IDE. Creating PIC projects in other IDEs really require a good knowledge of make build system. Also you will need to integrate the debugger bridge (it is MDB in your case) in order to debug your programs within the IDE.
In my case I tried to develop an existing project both in KDevelop IDE and Eclipse CDT IDE using the make files generated by MPLAB X IDE. Eventually I managed to get the both IDEs compiling the code. But I couldn't go further and integrate symbol recognition and debug bridge.
As a matter of fact the Microchip provides the IDEs as open source for those who want to integrate them into their desired environment. However as I said before, it requires a good knowledge to be able to manage and integrate all those apps in one environment.
If you are interested to learn more about the open source SDK of Microchip go ahead and have a look at ---> [openSource4Pic](http://www.opensource4pic.org/content/).
But as per my experience on developing application for PIC micros, you will get the best experience in MPLAB X since it is well integrated and featured nearly all needed tools.